# `gradle build` stuck at compileJava

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I execute the following command

> gradle clean build --debug --scan --info --stacktrace

the terminal shows

> ...
>
> Task :compileJava
>   Resolving global dependency management for project 'mooncake'
>   Excluding [org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api, com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java]
>   Excluding []
>   Custom actions are attached to task ':compileJava'.
>   Caching disabled for task ':compileJava' because:
>     Build cache is disabled
>   Task ':compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
>     No history is available.
>   All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':compileJava'.
>   Full recompilation is required because no incremental change information is available. This is usually caused by clean builds or changing compiler arguments.
>   Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
>   <=------------> 7% EXECUTING [9m 25s]
>   :compileJava

It takes too long to compile

gradle 5.6.2
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
//apply plugin: 'idea'

group = 'com.xxx'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    //maven{ url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    implementation "com.h2database:h2"
    implementation "com.googlecode.plist:dd-plist:1.21"
    implementation "net.dongliu:apk-parser:2.6.9"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.8.2'
    implementation 'com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.59'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation "junit:junit"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    testImplementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    testImplementation "com.h2database:h2"
    testImplementation "com.googlecode.plist:dd-plist:1.21"
    testImplementation "net.dongliu:apk-parser:2.6.9"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    testImplementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.8.2'
    testImplementation 'com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.59'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    testImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

}
```

Comment: are you sure that you didn't include planty of jars here by "implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']"?

Comment: @Dejan only 4 jars

Answer (score 2):

Now, I fixed it by updating my jdk to openjdk@1.13.0